# Atom: React-redux / node: cannot find module

Tags: node.js, react-native, atom-editor, eslint

I'm using atom:
The following packages have been installed: linter-eslint and linter

The following has been installed in the project's folder:

```
npm install --save-dev eslint-config-rallycoding
eslint-config-rallycoding@3.1.0 node_modules/eslint-config-rallycoding
├── eslint-plugin-react@6.4.1 (doctrine@1.5.0, jsx-ast-utils@1.3.3)
├── eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y@2.2.3 (object-assign@4.1.0, damerau-levenshtein@1.0.3, jsx-ast-utils@1.3.3)
├── eslint-plugin-import@1.16.0 (lodash.endswith@4.2.1, contains-path@0.1.0, object-assign@4.1.0, lodash.cond@4.5.2, lodash.find@4.6.0, lodash.findindex@4.6.0, builtin-modules@1.1.1, debug@2.2.0, doctrine@1.3.0, has@1.0.1, minimatch@3.0.3, pkg-dir@1.0.0, pkg-up@1.0.0, eslint-import-resolver-node@0.2.3, es6-map@0.1.4, es6-set@0.1.4)
├── eslint@3.9.0 (path-is-inside@1.0.2, natural-compare@1.4.0, strip-bom@3.0.0, ignore@3.2.0, imurmurhash@0.1.4, pluralize@1.2.1, globals@9.12.0, estraverse@4.2.0, strip-json-comments@1.0.4, esutils@2.0.2, progress@1.1.8, text-table@0.2.0, is-resolvable@1.0.0, babel-code-frame@6.16.0, user-home@2.0.0, debug@2.2.0, doctrine@1.5.0, levn@0.3.0, optionator@0.8.2, require-uncached@1.0.2, chalk@1.1.3, json-stable-stringify@1.0.1, mkdirp@0.5.1, glob@7.1.1, concat-stream@1.5.2, inquirer@0.12.0, is-my-json-valid@2.15.0, file-entry-cache@2.0.0, espree@3.3.2, js-yaml@3.6.1, shelljs@0.7.5, table@3.8.3, escope@3.6.0, lodash@4.16.4)
├── eslint-plugin-class-property@1.0.1 (requireindex@1.1.0, eslint@3.0.0)
└── babel-eslint@6.1.2 (lodash.assign@4.2.0, lodash.pickby@4.6.0, babylon@6.13.1, babel-types@6.18.0, babel-traverse@6.18.0)
```

The file .eslintrc contains:

```
{
"extends": "rallycoding"
}
```

But I'm getting the following error in atom:

```
 Error: Cannot find module 'eslint-config-rallycoding'
Referenced from: /Users/xtd/projects/react-native/RN-course/albums/.eslintrc
    at Object.resolve (/Users/xtd/.atom/packages/linter-eslint/node_modules/eslint/lib/util/module-resolver.js:74:19)
    at resolve (/Users/xtd/.atom/packages/linter-eslint/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:478:33)
    at load (/Users/xtd/.atom/packages/linter-eslint/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:495:26)
    at /Users/xtd/.atom/packages/linter-eslint/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:391:36
    at Array.reduceRight (native)
    at applyExtends (/Users/xtd/.atom/packages/linter-eslint/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:362:28)
    at Object.load (/Users/xtd/.atom/packages/linter-eslint/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:529:22)
    at loadConfig (/Users/xtd/.atom/packages/linter-eslint/node_modules/eslint/lib/config.js:63:33)
    at new Config (/Users/xtd/.atom/packages/linter-eslint/node_modules/eslint/lib/config.js:226:38)
    at CLIEngine.executeOnText (/Users/xtd/.atom/packages/linter-eslint/node_modules/eslint/lib/cli-engine.js:743:28)
```

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Inside the project folder, open terminal and try this:

```
npm install --save-dev eslint-config-rallycoding
```

Comment: I had already done it with no luck. Anyway. I build the project skeleton from scratch and it worked.